# Azure AD SSO with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity .net 7 api

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am developing .net 7 api which requires authentication/authorization through Azure AD SSO. I want to create default admin user in azure portal so that user can login to the system and create users and give them some permissions and roles. those infos I guess should be stored on the application side as well via Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity into db tables. I don't have experience with configuring Azure AD before. I am asking for some recommendations on how to properly configure both Azure and .net api to make authentication flow in good way. Appreciate any help

Comment: SSO is not for api, you need a client side  to save the SSO cookie. and request the right token in every request to pass an api.

Comment: yes you are right @QiangFu

Answer (score 0):

this is not complete SSO if you need Complete SSO content on (junaid042@outlook.com). Complete SSO need .net code. complete Single sign-on (SSO) is not easy. lot of code need for SSO.

here is a example of getting Access Token with Microsoft Singin.

you get access token easily try this this is Microsoft login in this you have received access token easily. first of all you need to create a app in Azure Protal [Azure Portal][1] creating new app you need to give Redirect URI Select platform Web and in your project you need to create a new .html file for Redirect URI. you can give localhost like this [https://localhost:44326/Redirect.html] and register app in your app overview you will receive {Application (client) ID ,Directory (tenant) ID,}. Now click on {Token configuration} in Token configuration page click on Add optional claim and select token type Access and Add. In Api permission you can add if you need. after all things now you need to use it. Use this code in your js file

```
let dialog;
function login() {
    let a = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=Add your client id here without any space &response_type=token&redirect_uri= your redirect_uri &scope=user.read%20mail.readwrite%20mail.send&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910";
    //let a = "https://localhost:44397/Redirect.html";

    // mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
    // Declare dialog as global for use in later functions.
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(a, { height: 30, width: 20 },
        function (asyncResult) {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
        }
    );
}
function processMessage(arg) {
    dialog.close();
    let messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
    console.log("accessToken", messageFromDialog)
  //  window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", messageFromDialog)
}
```

Add this code in your Redirect.html file

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>


        var address_Link = window.location.href;
        console.log(address_Link)
        var address_arr = address_Link.split("=");
        var address_Token = address_arr[1];
        var Id_Token = address_Token.split("&");
        var access_token = Id_Token[0];
        console.log(Id_Token)

        Office.onReady(function (appInfo) {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(access_token));

</script>
```

I loin url add your client id and your redirect_uri.
when login successfully you will receive Access Token in your js.
hopefully it is helpful for you I tried my best to explain you.